# echo {1..50..2} than pipe into another program in C

Tags: c, pipe

I have the command

```
echo {1..50..2} | ./assn3
```

and it prints out

```
The sum of 25 numbers is 625
```

This is in C and I don't know how `./assn3` reads in what has come from the pipe. Is this in `stdin` and I use `read()` or should I be using something else? I am just confused on where the echo goes for `assn3` to read it from?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `echo {1..50..2}` is written to the standard output, so using `read()` on the file descriptor of the standard input in the program the output is piped to will work.

Comment: Correct, but a better option for the OP would be to use the standard input functions such as `getc()` or `fgets()` or even `scanf()`.

Comment: I did not mention these on purpose, as the example given looks like a school assignment, and I am not too keen to rid people of chances to find solutions themselves when pointed into the right direction.

Comment: OK. btw, `getc()` and `fgetc()` are semantically equivalent.  `getc()` might be more efficient as it may be implemented as a macro.

Comment: True, but note that "Since it may be implemented as a macro, `getc()` may treat incorrectly a stream argument with side effects. In particular, `getc(*f++)` does not necessarily work as expected. Therefore, use of this function should be preceded by `#undef getc` in such situations; `fgetc()` could also be used." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getc.html).

Comment: @chqrlie Looking at your profile, I'm pretty certain you knew that. But maybe others didn't. :)

Comment: OK, but whoever uses `getc(*f++)` should be fired.  If such `FILE**` sorcery is useful, the programmer should be savvy enough to write `fgetc(*f++)` or `(getc)(*f++)`.  In a lifetime of C programming, reading innumerable sources from the weirdest backgrounds, I have never seen anything close to this.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` operator connects the standard output of the command on the LHS to the standard input of the command on the RHS.

The `echo` command (in Bash 4, not Bash 3) writes the odd numbers from 1 to 49 on a single line to its standard output.  The `assn3` program must read its standard input to get the data.  Underlying everything will be the `read()` system call, but the program probably uses the standard I/O library (`fgets()` or `getchar()` or `scanf()` or similar functions) to read the data.